# How to create dynamic routes in sh-service framework

Tags: php, web-services, frameworks

Please help me, how to create a custom routes in php sh-service framework.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$app->get('/name/:firstname',function($app,$req,$res){ 

   $res->json($req->firstname);

}
```

it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much it is working for me.

Try this format:

```
$app->get('/name/:firstname',function($app,$req,$res){ 

   echo $req->firstname;
}
```

Don't try this format:

```
$app->get('/name/{firstname}',function($app,$req,$res){ 

   $res->json($req->firstname);
}
```